# How to register for callbacks on a DB4O server?

Tags: .net, db4o, document-database

I have a DB4O server listening on a port

```
       IObjectServer server = Db4oClientServer.OpenServer("filename.db40", 11978);
```

How do i register for callbacks? For example how do i execute some custom code before an object is read or stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use EventRegistryFactory.ForObjectContainer(objectContainer);

For more information read here:

http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.13/net35/reference/html/reference/implementation_strategies/callbacks/event_registry_api.html

Best